# Can you put Hardy backer board on top of Mapie self leveler plus?

Tags: bathroom, plywood, self-leveling-concrete, backer-board

I have already applied self leveler in my bathroom over brand new plywood subfloor. I have got Mixed opinions if I can use Hardy backer board on top of the self leveler.

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: Self leveling compound has served me well when fixing old homes, I use several different brands of backer but hardy works fine I would rather have a flat level base under my backer than dips and voids that happen in my early days when I tried to fill with mortar, there will be many opinions out there but whatever provides a solid base that is level (or properly contoured for a drain) will make the best long term job.

Comment: Thanks Ed!  So I don't need to worry about screwing down the Hardy board threw the self leveler and breaking it up with the screws? Also I have just noticed there is a couple hairline cracks in the self leveler. should I worry about that?